# Is there a CSS only solution to make divs equal height in a vertical grid?

Tags: html, css, css-float, flexbox

I have a `.parent` div and within that I have an **unknown** number of `.child` divs. I need the child divs to be in a vertical grid and all of them need to be equal height. Unfortunately, I can't use javascript for this.

I have tried different combinations of `display: inline-block` and `float: left`, but I can't get the children to be the same height.

I am able to achieve same height using `display: table-cell` but then I run into another problem that the children don't split onto multiple lines if the total width exceeds the container width.

Is there a way to do this with pure css? I only need to support IE10+ if that helps (flexbox?)

Comment: `flexbox` can help (without setting explicit heights), but each row will have matching heights and heights on each row can differ...

Comment: That's not a problem. As long as it's the same height on each row.

Comment: ok, check out the demo I created below - it wraps with change in window width and each row has the same height...

Comment: You're a star!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a *wrapping* `flexbox` - see how the heights are auto-adjusted (due to the `align-items:stretch` property which is default) when the child divs wrap as you resize the window.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.wrapper > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    some text here some text here
  </div>

  <div>
    some text here
    <br/>more text here
  </div>

  <div>
    some text here
    <br/>more text here and some more and some more
  </div>

  <div>
    some text here
    <br/>more text here
    <br/>more text here
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use flexbox.

```
.parent{
    display: flex;
}
.child{
    flex:1;
}
```

Comment: How about the [partial support in IE10](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Will that cause problems with this setup?

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to break the children on to multiple lines if you resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using viewport units.

Something like this might work:

```
.child {
    height: 1vw;
}
```

This will make the child elements have 1/100 of the viewport width.

[To read more about viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

[Viewport units support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: This will make the children have scrollbars if the content exceeds that height.